Is function with period $1-f(0)$ constant given $f(x)=f(xf(0))$?
Function $f$ satisfies $f(x)=f(x+1-f(0))=f(xf(0))$ for every real $x$ and $f(0)≠1$. Does this imply that $f$ is constant?
At first, it seems that it could hold at least in case of working with rationals, but the nature of reals suggests that there could be some pathological solutions. I didn't manage to prove nor disprove either of claims.
I am aware of the fact, that in case $f(0)=0$, it implies $f(x)=f(0)=0$.
EDIT: Removed denoting $c=f(0)$ to reduce confusion.

Is there information on differentiability of f ?

Yes if f doesn’t change with c it is a constant. Imagine plotting f(x) and f(cx) on a graph then changing c, ie scaling the x axis, if the graphs still overlap f can only be a constant

Alternatively, put x=1/c and consider it a function of c, that shows explicitly f(1/c)=f(1) for all c

Did you mean to write $c=f(1)$?  or is $c=f(0)$ a separate condition?

@Maxime no, f can be any function.

@GrahamHesketh c is given by value of f(0). c could be only changed by changing f.

@lulu I am sorry for confusion, it is separate condition. I will edit answer to make it mere clear.

This question needs CONTEXT. Where did this question come from, for starters.

Doesn’t matter how you define the scaling factor, the principle remains the same you cannot map from the domain and some scaled version of the domain and get the same value for the function for all values of that domain unless the scale factor is one or the function is constant. The periodicity condition is irrelevant, the result stems from scale invariance.

Imagine f(0)=1/2, imagine plotting f(x) then you plot f(x/2) on the same graph, it will have the same shape but it will be stretched out along x. Its line can never coincide with that of f(x) unless stretching in the x axis left it completely unchanged, i.e it is a constant. It makes no difference what the scale factor is as long as it is not 1.

Suppose that $c\neq0$.
Now, let $\displaystyle S:=\{y\in\mathbb R\;:\;\exists s\in\mathbb N,\exists((n_k),(m_k))\in\mathbb Z^s\times\mathbb Z^s,\;y=(1-c)\sum_{k=1}^s c^{n_k}m_k\}$.
Then $1_S$ satisfy the hypothesis (since if $x\in S \Leftrightarrow cx\in S \Leftrightarrow x+(1-c)\in S$).
Now, is $1_S$ constant ? $S$ is countable (or finite if $c=1$) so strictly included in $\mathbb R$ so $f$ isn’t constant !
